# in Laravel DB, which of get with count vs get without count is more efficient?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, count

Now there are 2 ways of get from Laravel Database. And I want to know which is more efficient.

**1. get with count**

```
$cnt = \App\Models\Res_Times::where(...)
    ->count();

if ($cnt > 0) {
    $result = \App\Models\Res_Times::where(...)
        ->get();
}
```

**2. get directly**

```
$result = \App\Models\Res_Times::where(...)
    ->get();
```

I don't know PHP mysql count function is so fast worthy to use.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is better. In the first case you build 2 queries you fire up to the database. If there are maybe relationships laravel will not try to load them if there aren't no results.

Comment: Thanks mimo, Can you explain more in detail?

Answer (score 2):

The more efficient way to see if the response exists is to use `exists` because we determinate if the rows for the query actually exist before we actually loaded into the collection, for example:

```
$result = \App\Models\Res_Times::where(...)
if ($result->exists()) {
   return $result->get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks jycr753, Do you think count or exist is really need?

Comment: I do use exist when I need to add any conditional that it can't be added while using `when`.. all depends on the program you are writting

Comment: I think, without count() or exists(), get() maybe working well. Please let me know it is right or wrong.

Comment: @Alex it all depends on what you want to do with the result. but I think exists is a better option because it does not load anything into a collection to be able to count it.